# How to extract the Binding of a DataTemplate through its child elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, sender

I have a DataTemplate that is bound to a buisness class, it also contains a StackPanel:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type logic:Sensor}">
        <StackPanel Name="SensorPanel" MouseDown="SensorPanel_MouseDown">
            <TextBlock Name="ID" Text="{Binding}" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="Type" Text="{Binding Type}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When I click on the Stack panel I want to get the instance of the 'logic:sensor' via the sender parameter.

```
    private void SensorPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Is there any way to get to it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the sender to `FrameworkElement` and retrieve the `DataContext` property.